# Zurb Interchnage + Magento

Tags: magento, zurb-foundation

I have this weird bug which I can't figure out, so I am asking for help. I am building a Magento store using Zurb Foundation, for images I decided to uses their interchange script, however it does not work as it supposed. For some reason it removes the image tag completely from the dom instead of switching images. At first I thought it was a prototype/jquery/foundation conflict but it does not seem so.

Here is a link to the page with a bug - http://www.dressaccent.com/magento/jovani-4247-vechernee-plat-e-27356, you can see the image there but as soon as jquery/foundation kicks in it disappears.

Comment: After playing with it for some time it turned out to be a prototype conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue implementing Foundation 5 with Magento. Interchange would load the content but then the div or image container itself would vanish from the DOM.

I managed to get it working by commenting out the trigger on line 65 in foundation.interchange.js

```
        el.data('interchange-last-path', path);
        //trigger();
      });
```

Then it works fine. I'm sure this isn't the best solution, but has got it working for me.

EDIT: to get it to work for IMG as well, you need to also comment out the trigger for them like this:

```
if (/IMG/.test(el[0].nodeName)) {
        var orig_path = el[0].src;

        if (new RegExp(path, 'i').test(orig_path)) return;

        el[0].src = path;

        //return trigger(el[0].src);
      }
      var last_path = el.data('interchange-last-path');

      if (last_path == path) return;

      return $.get(path, function (response) {
        el.html(response);
        el.data('interchange-last-path', path);
        //trigger();
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well. Thanks @richkrirk for the solution.
I would like to post the updated version of fix for Foundation 5.3.x

```
      if (/IMG/.test(el[0].nodeName)) {
        var orig_path = el[0].src;

        if (new RegExp(path, 'i').test(orig_path)) return;

        el[0].src = path;

        //return trigger(el[0].src);
        return;
      }
      var last_path = el.data(this.data_attr + '-last-path'),
          self = this;

      if (last_path == path) return;

      if (/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)([?#].*)?/i.test(path)) {
        $(el).css('background-image', 'url('+path+')');
        el.data('interchange-last-path', path);
        //return trigger(path);
        return;
      }

      return $.get(path, function (response) {
        el.html(response);
        el.data(self.data_attr + '-last-path', path);
        //trigger();
      });
```

Basically, add comment to every trigger() call. However, you need to retain the return statements otherwise it will set background-image style on IMG tag.